# Convertir java.util.Date a java.sql.Date

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statements

Necesito hacer la conversión `java.util.Date` a `java.sql.Date`. He probado lo siguiente:

```
private long convertirDate(java.util.Date f1) {
    java.sql.Date fechaSalida = new java.sql.Date(f1.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

El problema es que la fecha `f1` viene en formato `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm` al convertir e insertar en base de datos me trunca la hora y minuto dejando siempre a `00:00`

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar la utilidad final de esos datos? Si es por ejemplo para insertar o actualizar, lo correcto sería usar `PreparedStatement` y dejar que JDBC haga el trabajo. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18615191/5587982), pero [**sobre todo esta** (aunque no sea la aceptada)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38809770/5587982), si usas Java 8+  y JDBC 4+.

Comment: Podrías poner la definición de tu tabla.